# How to update a datetime where it is NULL or '0000-00-00'?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

in my php app I need to update the `datatime` in mysql table where the column `datatime` is `null` or like `'0000-00-00'` and two foreign key have two specific values.

I try this code to update:

```
$query3="UPDATE prestiti SET DATA_FINE='".$datafine."' WHERE DATA_FINE='0000-00-00' AND ID_U=".$id_utente." AND ID_L=".$id_libro."";
$risultato4 = mysql_query($query3,$conn) or die ($query3);
```

The code doesn't work and when it works it change the column `DATA_FINE` in every record where the `ID_U` and `ID_L` correspond to the specific value also if `DATA_FINE` has already a value.

So what is the problem? I tried also to use `DATA_FINE IS NULL` into my `WHERE` but it doesn't work.

`$datafine` was setted like a datetime variable that I use to insert into another column and it works!

Comment: If the columns are datetime, they will have a time attached to them also. You will need to use DATA_FINE LIKE '%0000-00-00%' not =

Comment: DATETIME format is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and you're checking for `0000-00-00`. Btw `0000-00-00 00:00:00` != `null`. RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @Matt thanks now it works correctly

Comment: `WHERE DATA_FINE='0000-00-00 00:00:00'` would have worked here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt the answer to my question is:

```
$query3="UPDATE prestiti SET DATA_FINE='".$datafine."' WHERE DATA_FINE LIKE '%0000-00-00%' AND ID_U=".$id_utente." AND ID_L=".$id_libro."";
$risultato4 = mysql_query($query3,$conn) or die ($query3);
```

Where I edit `DATA_FINE='0000-00-00'` into `DATA_FINE LIKE '%0000-00-00%'`